# npm publish fails with "The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I have a project that i publish on a private npm repository.
Under `node v14.16.0 (npm v6.14.11)`, the command `npm publish` run well and my package is published on my private repository.

I upgraded npm to 7 to support peer dependencies installation.
Now under `node v15.12.0 (npm v7.6.3)`, the command `npm publish` fails with

> The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Any idea?

**Update**

npm 7.6.3 with node 14 as the same effect :

> The "path" argument must be of type string

**Update 2**

console output with flag `--verbose`

> npm verb cli [ npm verb cli
> '.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/bin/node', npm
> verb cli
> '.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/bin/npm', npm verb
> cli   'publish', npm verb cli   '--verbose' npm verb cli ] npm info
> using npm@7.6.3 npm info using node@v15.12.0 npm timing
> config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms npm timing
> config:load:file:.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc
> Completed in 2ms npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms npm
> timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms npm timing config:load:env
> Completed in 0ms npm timing
> config:load:file:MyProject/.npmrc
> Completed in 4ms npm timing config:load:project Completed in 5ms npm
> timing config:load:file:.npmrc Completed in 4ms
> npm timing config:load:user Completed in 4ms npm timing
> config:load:file:.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/etc/npmrc
> Completed in 1ms npm timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms npm
> timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms npm timing
> config:load:validate Completed in 0ms npm timing
> config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms npm timing
> config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms npm timing config:load Completed
> in 18ms npm verb npm-session 83e5ee6d9b1b9659 npm timing npm:load
> Completed in 82ms npm verb publish [ '.' ] npm timing command:publish
> Completed in 25ms npm verb stack TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The
> "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined npm verb
> stack     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5) npm verb stack
> at validateString (node:internal/validators:129:11) npm verb stack
> at join (node:path:1081:7) npm verb stack     at flatten
> (.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/flat-options.js:50:10)
> npm verb stack     at Publish.publishConfigToOpts
> (.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/publish.js:140:12)
> npm verb stack     at Publish.publish
> (.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/publish.js:58:32)

Comment: If a clean npm install doesn't help, you could try downgrading node to v14. Tools like n (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) and https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm will help with this.

Comment: @KunalNagpal npm 7.6.3 with node 14 as the same effect : `The "path" argument must be of type string`

Comment: Okay, could you try: `npm publish --verbose`?

Comment: @KunalNagpal I added the output console to the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the issue [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2834)

The workaround is to add a `cache` property to the `publishConfig` section of `package.json`

```
"publishConfig": {
    "cache": "cache/.npm",
    "registry": "https://mydomain/myrepo"
}
```

**Update**

The issue has been fixed in npm 7.7.0

Comment: The problem has since been fixed, as indicated in the issue you link to, in npm 7.7.0.

Comment: I'm on `7.9.0` and experience the issue

Comment: @vsync any solution?

Comment: @its4zahoor - sorry but I don't remember. Try remove the `publishConfig` property completely

Comment: but that will remove registry info as well.